# How to customize pagenumber position using fncychap

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr, fncychap

Using `fancypages` and two-sided documents, I used to set `\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}` to get the page number on the page away from the center. Now that I use the package `fncychap` it won't work on pages where I start a new chapter because of the style. Can anyone help me edit this somehow?

I am using LyX but am quite used to filling up the preample with LaTeX code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Note: There's no `fancypages` packages -- because of `\fancyfoot`, I assume you're using `fancyhdr`.)

Chaper-starting pages (with or without the `fncychap` package) use the `plain` pagestyle, so you have to redefine this style with `\fancypagestyle{plain}{<whatever>}`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhead{}%
  \renewcommand*{\headrule}{}%
  \fancyfoot{}%
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}%
}

\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]